# R error if statement 'argument is of length zero'

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I wrote three functions where two of the functions (namely **function1** and **function2**) is used in the other function of **populatedataset**.

I was running the function **populatedataset** when i got an error of `Error in if (num == 1) { : argument is of length zero`

I believe that it is due to **function2** due to the 'if (num == 1) {: ' portion.

```
function2 <- function(data, table, dict) {
  personindex <- substr(deparse(substitute(data)), start = 1, stop = 2)
  num <- table[person == as.character(personindex)]$newpersonality
  if (num == 1) {
    proptable <- data %>% inner_join(dict[score == 1]) %>% count(word)
    proportion <- sum(proptable$n)/nrow(data)
    return(proportion)
  }
  else {
    proptable <- data %>% inner_join(dict[score == 0]) %>% count(word)
    proportion <- sum(proptable$n/nrow(data))
    return(proportion)
  }
}


populatedataset <- function(data, table, dict) {
  list_a <- c(function1(data, dict), function2(data, table, dict))
  return (list_a)
}
```

I have been reading up on this error on other pages but I can't seem to find a solution related to this problem.

I would greatly appreciate any insight into this error!

Comment: This has *got* to be the [most common `r` question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+argument+is+of+length+zero).

Answer (score 6):

A `if` condition has to be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This error implicates that `num == 1` evaluates to a `logical(0)`. This is probably caused by `num` being empty, i.e. `numeric(0)`, because then you are comparing a numeric value of length 0 to 1 which gives a logical of length 0. You can wrap your condition `num == 1` with the `isTRUE` function which would turn the `logical(0)` into a `FALSE`:

```
if (isTRUE(num == 1)){....
```

The function `isTRUE` checks if the argument is the logical value `TRUE`. Since `num == 1` is `logical(0)` in this case, `isTRUE` will return `FALSE` and the `if` works as inteded.

On sidenote: `num` being `numeric(0)`is probably being caused by the fact that `person == as.character(personindex)` is not `TRUE` for any person so if you index your table no `newpersonality` value is returned. In this case you would run into the `else` portion of your `if`-`else`-construct if you use my solution.